# How to run python script results on Flask

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web, flask

I have created an app.py and index.html file. My problem is that I want to execute a python script with the input I gathered from POST when submit is clicked, and then display the script output on the same or different html page. I used CGI and Flask. I do not fully know how to proceed. I research online, but couldn't find anything very helpful. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
  return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/src_code/main.py", methods = ['POST'])
def run_app():
  id = request.form['id']
  name = request.form['name']
  url = request.form['url']

  if not id or not name or not url:
     return render_template('index.html')
  else:
      #execute the python script.

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

**EDIT:**

I have used the following code to import my function. At the end, though I have received an error when I clicked the submit button on index.html

```
   script_analyze = Analyzer()
   result = script_analyze.main()

   return render_template(results.html', data=result)

 AttributeError: 'WSGIRequestHandler' object has no attribute 'environ'
```

I am unsure why this attribute error is raised.

Comment: I don't see what's the problem, you already have all you need, just use a new template to return in the else.

Comment: how can i use a new template for return? Can you show me a sample? @polku

Comment: Use `return render_template('newtemplate.html', data=script_output)` like you already did, again I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: you have to check if its a `'POST'` statement, then do the above else use `return redirect(url_for('abc'))`

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. My problem is that I do not know how to execute the python script(meaning that I need to run another .py inside run_app(), and how to store the output of that .py as script_output.

Comment: if youre getting started with flask I'd highly recommend Miguel Grinbergs [Flask Mega Tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world). It's really good.

Comment: It depends on what this script is doing, but the easiest way should be to turn it into a function ( if it's not already one) that returns what you want to display, so you can import and call it like any other one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to execute another Python script... If you are able to `import` the other script then you can just use something like the following to call it and store the results - assuming the other script is a value-returning function.

```
from othermodule import function_to_run
...
# where you want to call it
result = function_to_run()
```

Then you can use `render_template` as others have said, passing this result as the data to the template (or simply return the result if it's already in the format you want to output with Flask).

Does that work, or is the script you want to run something that this wouldn't work for? Let us know more about the script if it's an issue.

Comment: I have tried your code, I managed to import my class it wasn't a module. However, this time I have received the following error relevant to the import. 
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequestHandler' object has no attribute 'environ' @LindsayWard

Comment: Hi. Your edit doesn't show how you `import`ed anything. Can you include this as well?
Do you use `environ` anywhere?